# Twitter Bootstrap using block level labels and inputs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, forms, label, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [Twitter bootstrap for Rails/SASS](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass) and have notice that it applies a `display: block;` style to my `labels`,`label inputs` and `label textareas`.

I am using form tags to generate a check box with a label, but the block style move the two onto different line:

```
  <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
  <%= f.label :remember_me %>
```

My question is two fold. Should I be doing it this way? and if so how best should I override Twitter Bootstraps defaults. I would rather not have lots of `!important` flags in my CSS if I can avoid it.

Comment: Don't know much about rails but i don't think you're containing your checkbox properly, from the documentation i see that you need to format it like so: http://jsfiddle.net/nGyVe/

Comment: that works, but I am having to hard code it rather than using rails helpers, which seems less maintainable long term. It would be great if the two frameworks could coexist more peacefully.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can do it the bootstrap way and pass in a label block

```
<%= f.label :remember_me, :class => "checkbox" do %>
  <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>remember me
<% end %>
```

on this way the checkbox also gets checkt if you click on the text. Much nicer!

Comment: worked a treat, although isn't the label clicking the default behaviour of inline label/inputs anyway?

Comment: I'm using the same code verbatim and it still insists on displaying the checkbox and the label on two separate lines.

Comment: I was able to fix it by assigning the checkbox a custom class and setting its width to auto. (Bootstrap was setting it to 100%, which made the label not fit in the same line.)